# How to setup OCI8 on Red Hat 7.9 with REMI/RPM repository?

Tags: linux, php, redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-linux, rhel-7

I am very much new to linux and my project uses Oracle Instant Client. I want to install OCI8 on Red Hat 7.9 but I don't know if I need to install basic/devel/rpm/remi version. I am following this document:

https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/installing-oci8-on-rhel/

Will it work or not I don't know. Please write your views or thoughts on this. Any clue will work for me.

---

**EDIT**: I managed to install OCI8 (`php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64.rpm`) in Red Hat 7 and added `extension=oci8.so`, `extension_dir='path to oci8.ini'` but still `phpinfo()` doesn't show oci8 package.

Also I installed Oracle Instant Client 19.11 on my Linux server. Do I need to set a path variable? Or what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Linked page seems outdated.

Using "remi" repository, you don't have to build anything, only to install the proper set of packages.

To install the PHP Stack, see the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

To install the Oracle extensions, see [Installation of Oracle extensions for PHP](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP)

Comment: what if I want rpm version of oci8 for linux? where can I find that?

Comment: Above instructions are for RPM... on RHEL / CentOS...

Comment: Remi I need one info from you. where can i find this rpm version of oci8. php-oci8-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64. I tried everything but I can't find it

Comment: This one does not exists (oci8 extension for php in default repository)

Comment: Hello Remi, I installed this package php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64 but still I am getting oci_connect() error. Please help. I don't know what to do anymore. These packages are installed php-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-ldap-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-gd-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-22.el7.noarch
php-odbc-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-xml-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-pdo-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-process-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64

Comment: Have read the link to the howto in my answer ?

Comment: I read everything but still I don't understand what to do :-( . I will post in your website forum.